# Not able to set defaultChecked value in Radio button react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to set the defaultChecked value in Radio button ReactJS.

default value is depends on API fetched data.

Below is my useState:

```
const [edit_data, setEditData] = useState([]);
```

API Call

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let url = window.location.href
            var array_fragment = url.toString().split("/")
            var content_id = array_fragment[array_fragment.length - 1]
            const result = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/edit_content/${content_id}`);
            setEditData(result.data);
        })();
    }, []);
```

I have tried this set last value(Other) radio button but actual want to set Lecture radio button.
edit_data.content_type return the "Lecture" value.

```
defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Value' ? "true" : "false"}
```

React radio button code:

```
<fieldset>
    <Form.Label>Content Type</Form.Label>
    <Row className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center py-4" value={contenttype} onChange={(e) => setContentType(e.target.value)}>
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <Form.Check
                defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Lecture' ? "true" : "false"}
                type="radio"
                defaultValue="option1"
                label="Lecture"
                name="x"
                value="Lecture"
                id="radio1"
                htmlFor="radio1"
            />
        </Col>
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <Form.Check
                defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Seminar' ? "true" : "false"}
                type="radio"
                defaultValue="option2"
                label="Seminar"
                name="x"
                value="Seminar"
                id="radio2"
                htmlFor="radio2"
            />
        </Col>
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <Form.Check
                defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Study Material' ? "true" : "false"}
                type="radio"
                defaultValue="option3"
                label="Study Material"
                name="x"
                value="Study Material"
                id="radio3"
                htmlFor="radio3"
            />
        </Col>
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <Form.Check
                defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Other' ? "true" : "false"}
                type="radio"
                defaultValue="option4"
                label="Other"
                name="x"
                value="Other"
                id="radio4"
                htmlFor="radio4"
            />
        </Col>
    </Row>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the response from `await axios(\`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/edit_content/${content_id}\`);`?

Comment: @HanchenJiang json response is {
  added_on: null,
  category: [1],
  content_file: "/media/media/download_QpgAjoK.jpg",
  content_type: "Lecture",
  description: "nil",
  expiration: "2021-12-09",
  id: 3,
  publish_now: true,
  schedule_release: "2021-12-23",
  school_profile: 4,
  show: 1,
  shows_name: "nil",
  sponsor_link: "nil",
  status: false,
  subtitle: "niln",
  tag: (2) [1, 2],
  title: "nil",
  topic: [1],
  user: 7
}

Comment: You've initialised `edit_data` as an array so it won't have a `content_type` property on the initial render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have replace `"true"` with `true` and `"false"` with `false`. Strings are treated as `true`. Empty strings are treated as `false`.

`defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Value' ? true : false}`

You have to add the `checked` attribute to the radio as mentioned below and also change the state on `onClick` event if you want the radio button to toggle.

```
<Form.Check
defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Study Material' ? true : false}
checked={edit_data.content_type === 'Study Material' ? true : false}
type="radio"
defaultValue="option3"
label="Study Material"
name="x"
value="Study Material"
id="radio3"
htmlFor="radio3"
/>
```

Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-benji-6ijod?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark%22) which demonstrates the solution.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No not showing any errors related to defaultChecked

Comment: Check the edited response please

Comment: I have changed defaultChecked={edit_data.content_type === 'Study Material' ? true : false}
checked={edit_data.content_type === 'Study Material' ? true : false} in code its set the defaultChecked redio button but after that i am not able change redio button

Comment: That is because you are not handling the `onClick` event and changing the value of `edit_data.content_type`. Check the link, I shared in the end of the answer.

Comment: I have add onClick event like this:  `onClick={() => {
                                                    setContentType({ content_type: !edit_data.content_type });
                                                }}` but still not working

Comment: First of all, where are you even using `setContentType`? Second, `content_type` is a String not a Boolean, so why are you using `!` operator with it? Look below for the changes:
` onClick={() => {  setEditData({ ... edit_data, content_type: 'something else' });   }}

Comment: last changes working now thanks